# How to call an 'action' using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, action

I'm using iOS SDK to post an action to the user's wall.
I've just created an action using facebook's developer dashboard.
Action contains only an object called 'Quake'.
That's the code:
[That's the code which I've received from Facebook](http://pastebin.com/KGzWJybn)
It contains the app id, url, and all the other fields.

This is the code I've used in my app:

```
Facebook *fb = (Facebook*)([SHKFacebook facebook]);
NSMutableDictionary *earthquake = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [quake.URLToInfo absoluteString],@"url",
                            [quake mainLocationForZone:zone],@"title",
                            @"[LINK]",@"image",
                            text,@"description", nil];
[fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/shakeearthquakes:check?access_token=[ACCESSTOKEN]" 
               andParams: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:earthquake,@"quake", nil]
           andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
             andDelegate: self];
```

(I've already authorized my app to post action using "publish_actions").

With these settings (passing a dictionary as "quake" object params for my object) it crashes.
-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa05b3f0
So probability this is not the right way to pass parameters for objects.
What's the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You area putting an NSMutableDictionary(earthquake) object in another NSMutableDictionary(autoreleased) object. Are you sure this is what you intended? why not just pass earthquake for the "andParams" paramater?